# How to rename enum ItemsChoiceType generated by XSD.exe?

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd2code

When you are generating c# class from XSD any choice will be represented as enum.
And i didn't find any way to make this name custom.
The problem is that when i'm using 2+ choices in xsd generator will produce *ItemsChoiceType*, *ItemsChoiceType1*, etc.
And this can break naming compatibility.

Is it possible to set custom name instead of *ItemsChoiceType*?

Answer (score 0):

That name is defined into the XSD, if you do not hace chance to edit the XSD is not posible ...

( is it an model enumeration?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/bb347480(v=vs.90).aspx )

Comment: The name is not in the XSD (I have the same issue). I have a xs:element and use that in an array. The code generation creates ItemsChoiceType and ItemsChoiceType1 automatically.